# how to execute clearing of the procedure cache for one database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have made a maintenance plan for my db. This plan contains several tasks, i can choose that every task is for specific db.

But dbcc freeproccache does not have any mentioning about specific db. I'm worried that this procedure will be executed for all databases that my SQL server has.

How can i execute clearing of cache for a single database?

Answer (score 1):

dbcc freeproccache functions at the Sql Server instance level, so yes, it does effect every database under a particular instance. To explicitly clear plans for a single database, you could run the command:
DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB().

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd get better answers to this question on dba.stackexchange.com.

A simple explanation is that DBCC freeprocache is an instance level command, and it will affect all DBs on the same instance.

I need to know why you want to clear plans to give you a better answer to this question. What are you trying to solve?